# How can I align my search button to the right?

Tags: css, search, button

I'm not well versed in front end web design or CSS. Using a pre-made template from Foundation, however my code for a search button is not aligning like the example button.

Using this template: http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/workspace.html

Can someone tell me how I can move the search button to the right as in pic where the blue button is located?

[image]

This is what I am using now:

`<input type="submit" value="Search" style="float: right;">`

Fiddle: [Search button code](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Yst/4/)

```
<ul class="right">
<li class="search">
    <li class="has-button">
        /* Original template form */
        {#<form>#}
            {#<input type="search">#}
        {#</form>#}

        /* My form with code */
        <form action="{{ path('sym_corp_search') }}" method="GET">
            <label><input type="search" name="q" value={{ app.request.query.get('q') }}></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" style="float: right;">
        </form>
    </li>
</li>

/* Original form button in blue */
<li class="has-button">
    <a class="small button" href="#">Search</a>
</li>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: updated with the code, looks odd though

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X344d/

Comment: @MuhammadAli No this didn't work. This put my search button to the left slightly but it's still on the bottom.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W2Yst/5/ i updated at your code

Comment: Just tried this and no change it's still on the bottom, I think it's something with Foundation's pre-made CSS that's causing it to not work. Using this template: http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/workspace.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the foundation classes, you can manage to perform this layout with your own inputs, your code will look like this:

```
<ul class="right">
    <form action="{{ path('acme_demo_search') }}" method="GET">
        <li class="search">
            <label><input type="search" name="q" value="{{ app.request.query.get('q') }}" /></label>
        </li>
        <li class="has-button">
            <input type="submit" value="Search"  class="small button" />
        </li>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use margin property like margin-left:50%; or more and you can also use ... tag but it will make button position to center. float:right is can be used in div, Not in button.

Answer (score 0):

Move your button in a div :
`<div id="mybtn"><input type="submit" value="Search"></div>` 
add CSS :
 `#mybtn {
float : right;
display : inline-block;
}`

Comment: Tried this, the search button still remains on the bottom. Again, I think it's the existing CSS that's preventing the button from moving up to the right.