# How can I use this template search button in place of my submit button in form?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

New to front end design as I'm mostly working in the backend. The problem is, I have a template that I'm using from Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/workspace.html

I've tried to use my button (the one in gray) instead of theirs (one in blue) but for some reason my submit button will not move up in place of the template blue button.

So, instead I would like to use their blue button in the pic below instead of the search button from my form submit.

[image]

How can I use their button instead of the form submit button?

**Search html code**

```
<ul class="right">
    <li class="search">
        <li class="has-button">
            {# My search form #}
            <form action="{{ path('acme_demo_search') }}" method="GET">
                <label><input type="search" name="q" value={{ app.request.query.get('q') }}></label>
                <div class="btn">
                <ul class="right">

                    <div class="btn">
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" style="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

               </ul>
               </div>
            </form>
        </li>
    </li>

    {# Blue Search button code from the Foundation template #}
    <li class="has-button">
        <a class="small button" href="#">Search</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry but i have to ask in order to help you...you want therir button style as a subbmit button aren't you??...clarify me this please..

Comment: Yes, I want to use their button if it's possible, my button works but I can't align it correctly.

Comment: ok :-D well do you have the style that is calling??i think that this could be solved in css...

Comment: Did a search for 'small button' and 'has-button' but it doesn't appear in the foundation.css file...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In foundation you can use button styles in an input element maintaining its style concept, to use your submit button with foundation styles just use:

```
<ul class="right">
<form action="{{ path('acme_demo_search') }}" method="GET">
    <li class="search">
        <label><input type="search" name="q" value="{{ app.request.query.get('q') }}" /></label>
    </li>
    <li class="has-button">
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  class="small button" />
    </li>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok I see their button now, but it's still on the bottom, having the alignment issue. When I search for 'small button' in the foundation.css file it doesn't come up. I've all these solutions and yet my search button still stays on the bottom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720453/how-can-i-align-my-search-button-to-the-right

Comment: @chance I believe your are not finding the "small button" class because they are two separate classes. Look for .small and .button instead. With css you can combine classes with a space which looks like what they have done there.

Comment: @chance try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/bGVw6/ , is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @Gabriel Sezefredo I'm trying to get the my search button where the blue button is in the picture. I've tried multiple solutions on the other thread but for some reason my button will not move to the upper right next the box.

Comment: I've tried wrapping the <input type> in a <div class="btn"> then using CSS for the #btn but the button still doesn't move up next to the search box.

Comment: No problem @chance, Foundation can manage inputs and buttons very well, if you are stuck with something, try visiting their kitchen sink: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/kitchen_sink.html it helps a lot ;)

Comment: @GabrielSezefredo Thank you sir, I was pulling hair out trying to figure this out. Will check out that link.